# Как правильно указать на счеты во множественном числе?

Tags: падежи, множественное-число

Канцелярских счёт или канцелярских счётов? Как правильно в родительном падеже?

Comment: Вы о счётах - предмете (архаичном калькуляторе) или о счёте - финансовом документе?

Comment: О калькуляторе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В соответствии с «Грамматическим словарем русского языка», признанным Минобрнауки нормативным, в родительном падеже должно быть «счётов» (не «счето́в» и не «счёт»).

[https://gramdict.ru/search/счеты](https://gramdict.ru/search/%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B)

Answer (score 2):

*Счёты* "abacus" is a *plurale tantum*.

Most authors treat its genitive as if it were formed from the masculine noun *счёт*, using paradigm 1a (in Zaliznyak's notation), so *канцелярских счётов*.

> - Для целей практич. использования общих правил в рукописях рассматривалось много примеров реального содержания и излагался т. н. дощаной счет ― прототип русских счетов. [А. Н. Колмогоров. Математика (1954-1987)]
> - Кока окончил строительный факультет, но во Франции его диплом не был признан, а в Тбилиси он работать не хотел: вид деревянных счетов и допотопных рейсфедеров повергал его в уныние. [Михаил Гиголашвили. Чертово колесо (2007)]
> - Представители искусства, «чистой» науки, прикладных знаний, всевозможные работники пера и конторских счетов и проч. все в большей и большей мере делаются жертвами «рынка» и крупного капитала, начинают квалифицировать свое положение, как положение «пролетарское». [В. М. Шулятиков. Из теории и практики классовой борьбы (1907)]

There's a set expression *сбросить со счётов*. In the modern language, many speakers parse it as *сбросить со счето́в*, but its original form referred to the abacus and was stressed on the penultimate syllable.

In the pre-reform orthography, adjective endings changed in the plural nominative depending on the gender. All the adjectives I was able to find modifying this word use the masculine form: *миллiонные счёты, русскiе счёты*, not the feminine form: **миллiонныя счёты, *русскiя счёты*. That doesn't completely rule out paradigm 1с (similar to *грузин, солдат* etc.), but it does rule out any feminine base form that could have produced **счёт* in the genitive.